# Avoid GC pressure with Reactor Publisher

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I search for a way to correctly employ Publishers from Project Reactor without producing useless GC pressure by instantiating the whole pipeline on each call.

In our code a typical handle function answering inter service HTTP requests looks like so:

```
final List<Function<ChangeEvent, Mono<Void>>> triggerOtherMicroservices;

@PostMapping("/handle")
public Mono<Void> handle(@RequestBody ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
    return Mono
            .defer(() -> someService.callToAnotherMicroServiceToFetchData(changeEvent))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .map(this::mapping)
            .flatMap(data -> databaseService.save(data))
            .thenMany(Flux.fromIterable(triggerOtherMicroservices).flatMap(t -> t.apply(changeEvent)))
            .then();
}
```

If I understand correctly this means, on each invocation of `handle` the whole pipeline (which normally has huge stacktraces) needs to be instantiated (and thus collected later).

My question is: Can I somehow "prepare" the whole flow once and reuse it later?

I was thinking about something like `Mono.create( ... ) ....`. Or, am I completely wrong and there is no need to think about optimization here?

EDIT:

Thinking further I could do:

```
final List<Function<ChangeEvent, Mono<Void>>> triggerOtherMicroservices;

final Mono<Void> mono = Mono
        .defer(() -> Mono
                .subscriberContext()
                .map(context -> context.get("event"))
                .flatMap(event -> someService.callToAnotherMicroServiceToFetchData(event))
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(data -> databaseService.save(data))
        .thenMany(Mono
                .subscriberContext()
                .map(context -> context.get("event"))
                .flatMap(event -> Flux
                        .fromIterable(triggerOtherMicroservices)
                        .flatMap(t -> t.apply(event)))
        )
        .then(); 

public Mono<Void> handle(@Validated ChangeEvent changeEvent) throws NoSuchElementException {
    return mono.subscriberContext(context -> context.put("event", changeEvent));
}
```

Anyway, I doubt this is what `subscriberContext` is meant for.

Comment: Is it more a theoretical question or are you running into issues?

Comment: One optimization I can think of is to replace the lambdas with referenced methods. But no clue how much that impacts the memory footprint.

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt Well, I wouldn't call it theoretical. It is a question related to high throughput, low latency optimization. There is no functional issue, just cpu/memory utilization in our production. But I don't aim for general java optimizations like replacing the lambdas (which as far as I know, in newer JVMs shouldn't really make a difference). The question is related to reactor and GC pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: There are many JVM implementations and this answer doesn't claim to have tested all of them, nor to be a general statement for all possible situations.

According to https://www.bettercodebytes.com/the-cost-of-object-creation-in-java-including-garbage-collection/, it is possible that there is no overhead of object creation when objects only live within a method. This is, since the JIT doesn't actually instantiate the object but rather executes the contained methods directly.
Hence, there is also no garbage collection required later on.

A test of this combined with the question can be implemented like so:

Controller:

```
final List<Function<Event, Mono<Void>>> triggerOtherMicroservices = Arrays.asList(
        event -> Mono.empty(),
        event -> Mono.empty(),
        event -> Mono.empty()
);

final Mono<Void> mono = Mono
        .defer(() -> Mono
                .subscriberContext()
                .<Event>map(context -> context.get("event"))
                .flatMap(this::fetch)
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(this::duplicate)
        .flatMap(this::duplicate)
        .flatMap(this::duplicate)
        .flatMap(this::duplicate)
        .thenMany(Mono
                .subscriberContext()
                .<Event>map(context -> context.get("event"))
                .flatMapMany(event -> Flux
                        .fromIterable(triggerOtherMicroservices)
                        .flatMap(t -> t.apply(event))
                )
        )
        .then();

@PostMapping("/event-prepared")
public Mono<Void> handle(@RequestBody @Validated Event event) throws NoSuchElementException {
    return mono.subscriberContext(context -> context.put("event", event));
}

@PostMapping("/event-on-the-fly")
public Mono<Void> handleOld(@RequestBody @Validated Event event) throws NoSuchElementException {
    return Mono
            .defer(() -> fetch(event))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .flatMap(this::duplicate)
            .flatMap(this::duplicate)
            .flatMap(this::duplicate)
            .flatMap(this::duplicate)
            .thenMany(Flux.fromIterable(triggerOtherMicroservices).flatMap(t -> t.apply(event)))
            .then();
}


private Mono<Data> fetch(Event event) {
    return Mono.just(new Data(event.timestamp));
}

private Mono<Data> duplicate(Data data) {
    return Mono.just(new Data(data.a * 2));
}
```

Data:

```
long a;

public Data(long a) {
    this.a = a;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data{" +
            "a=" + a +
            '}';
}
```

Event:

```
 @JsonSerialize(using = EventSerializer.class)
 public class Event {
     UUID source;
     long timestamp;

     @JsonCreator
     public Event(@JsonProperty("source") UUID source, @JsonProperty("timestamp") long timestamp) {
         this.source = source;
         this.timestamp = timestamp;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return "Event{" +
                 "source=" + source +
                 ", timestamp=" + timestamp +
                 '}';
     }
 }
```

EventSerializer:

```
 public class EventSerializer extends StdSerializer<Event> {

     public EventSerializer() {
         this(null);
     }

     public EventSerializer(Class<Event> t) {
         super(t);
     }

     @Override
     public void serialize(Event value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
         jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
         jsonGenerator.writeStringField("source", value.source.toString());
         jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("timestamp", value.timestamp);
         jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
     }
 }
```

and finally the test itself:

```
 @SpringBootTest
 @AutoConfigureWebTestClient
 class MonoAssemblyTimeTest {

     @Autowired
     private WebTestClient webTestClient;

     final int number_of_requests = 500000;

     @Test
     void measureExecutionTime() throws IOException {
         measureExecutionTime("on-the-fly");
         measureExecutionTime("prepared");
     }

     private void measureExecutionTime(String testCase) throws IOException {
         warmUp("/event-" + testCase);

         final GCStatisticsDifferential gcStatistics = new GCStatisticsDifferential();
         long[] duration = benchmark("/event-" + testCase);

         StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
         int plotPointsInterval = (int) Math.ceil((float) number_of_requests / 1000);

         for (int i = 0; i < number_of_requests; i++) {
             if (i % plotPointsInterval == 0) {
                 output.append(String.format("%d , %d %n", i, duration[i]));
             }
         }

         Files.writeString(Paths.get(testCase + ".txt"), output.toString());

         long totalDuration = LongStream.of(duration).sum();
         System.out.println(testCase + " duration: " + totalDuration / 1000000 + " ms.");
         System.out.println(testCase + " average: " + totalDuration / number_of_requests + " ns.");
         System.out.println(testCase + ": " + gcStatistics.get());
     }

     private void warmUp(String path) {
         UUID source = UUID.randomUUID();
         IntStream.range(0, number_of_requests).forEach(i -> call(new Event(source, i), path));
         System.out.println("done with warm-up for path: " + path);
     }

     private long[] benchmark(String path) {
         long[] duration = new long[number_of_requests];

         UUID source = UUID.randomUUID();
         IntStream.range(0, number_of_requests).forEach(i -> {
             long start = System.nanoTime();
             call(new Event(source, i), path).returnResult().getResponseBody();
             duration[i] = System.nanoTime() - start;
         });
         System.out.println("done with benchmark for path: " + path);
         return duration;
     }

     private WebTestClient.BodySpec<Void, ?> call(Event event, String path) {
         return webTestClient
                 .post()
                 .uri(path)
                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .bodyValue(event)
                 .exchange()
                 .expectBody(Void.class);
     }

     private static class GCStatisticsDifferential extends GCStatistics {

         GCStatistics old = new GCStatistics(0, 0);

         public GCStatisticsDifferential() {
             super(0, 0);
             calculateIncrementalGCStats();
         }

         public GCStatistics get() {
             calculateIncrementalGCStats();
             return this;
         }

         private void calculateIncrementalGCStats() {
             long timeNew = 0;
             long countNew = 0;

             for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gc : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {

                 long count = gc.getCollectionCount();

                 if (count >= 0) {
                     countNew += count;
                 }

                 long time = gc.getCollectionTime();

                 if (time >= 0) {
                     timeNew += time;
                 }
             }

             time = timeNew - old.time;
             count = countNew - old.count;

             old = new GCStatistics(timeNew, countNew);
         }

     }

     private static class GCStatistics {
         long count, time;

         public GCStatistics(long count, long time) {
             this.count = count;
             this.time = time;
         }

         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return "GCStatistics{" +
                     "count=" + count +
                     ", time=" + time +
                     '}';
         }
     }

 }
```

The results are not always the same, but the "on-the-fly" method constantly outperforms the "prepared" method. Plus, the "on-the-fly" method has way less garbage collections.

A typical result looks like:

> done with warm-up for path: /event-on-the-fly
>
> done with benchmark for path: /event-on-the-fly
>
> on-the-fly duration: 42679 ms.
>
> on-the-fly average: 85358 ns.
>
> on-the-fly: GCStatistics{count=29, time=128}
>
> done with warm-up for path: /event-prepared
>
> done with benchmark for path: /event-prepared
>
> prepared duration: 44678 ms.
>
> prepared average: 89357 ns.
>
> prepared: GCStatistics{count=86, time=67}

This result were done on a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), 2,4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, 64 GB 2667 MHz DDR4.

Note: Comments, better answers, or ... are still very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First, take some measurment to decide if GC pressure is really high and is worth to bother.

Then, use some object-oriented library which allows you to explicitely create pipline objects, and reuse it for multiple requests. Look at Vert.x, for example (I never use it). My library Df4j allows to create and reuse computational graph of any topology, not only linear pipelines , but it does not contain modules to perform HTTP requests.   However, Df4j implements reactive streams protocol and so can be connected to any compatible network library.

Comment: Ok thanks, but at the moment I don’t consider moving to another implementation of the `Flow` package.